# CLI Linux Operating System

Tags: linux, operating-system, command-line-interface

I am looking for a Linux distribution that uses a Command Line Interface. No GUI. It must be installable on a modern 64 bit computer. It should also use bash, ksh or sh. Thanks in advance!

~ FieryJaguar

Comment: All the Linux distros come with a CLI.  Do you want one that *removes* the GUI?

Comment: This question should go to superuser.com.

Comment: @unxnut No. I want one that is only a CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Debian](http://www.debian.org/), [Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/), and [Slackware](http://www.slackware.com/) all come with text-based installers, and although like all modern distros they all install the X Window System by default, they also all give sufficiently fine-grained control over the installation process that you can easily deselect the packages for X, the window manager, and any other GUI software and thus create a purely CLI-driven system.

Comment: @user2151887: No problem.  I've been using Linux long enough that I remember when CLI-based installers were the norm and it was customary to not install X on a server to save on disk and memory usage, so I can appreciate your motivation.  Of the three I mentioned I like Debian best, but Arch seems to have the most active community of people who like to tweak their installs file by file, while Slackware has been around the longest and has a rock-solid reputation.  Good luck!